# Unable to hide "Chrome is being controlled by automated software" infobar within Chrome v76

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

After updating Chrome to version 76, I cannot figure out how to hide the "Chrome is being controlled by automated software..." notification overriding some controls on the page.

The latest stable release of ChromeDriver is indeed 76.0.3809.68.
The following code worked with Chrome 75 and ChromeDriver 74.

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--test-type");
options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
options.AddArguments("disable-infobars");
options.AddArguments("--disable-notifications");
options.AddArguments("enable-automation");
options.AddArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
options.AddArguments("start-maximized");
var driver = new ChromeDriver(driverLocation, options, ScriptTimeout);
```

Comment: That sounds like an issue with Chrome, not really C#

Answer (score 72, accepted):

As of 1 Aug 2019 - You can send the excludeswitch - enable-automation to hide the message. and to disable pop up 'Disable developer mode extensions' set 
useAutomationExtension=false . [Refer for useAutomationExtension](https://github.com/bayandin/chromedriver/commit/22fb21bc10fbaf67e6316cbf1cc71dbf310cf7a9#diff-1a3ffafe40de9dd2731f39f136f20189)

Tested on : Windows 10
Version 76.0.3809.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)
ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.68

--enable-automation : Inform users that their browser is being controlled by an automated test [Reference](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

```
     "goog:chromeOptions": {

        "excludeSwitches": [ "enable-automation" ],
        "useAutomationExtension": false
     }
```

**In C# :**

To disable pop up "Disable developer mode extensions" and automation info-bar message .

```
options.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation");
options.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);
```

**In JAVA :**

```
options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
```

**In Python :**

```
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
```

**In Protractor :**

Add below capabilities in conf.js/conf.ts

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    "goog:chromeOptions": {
      "excludeSwitches": [ "enable-automation" ],
      "useAutomationExtension": false
   }
  },
```

Comment: @g-victor Make sure to remove options.AddArguments("enable-automation"); this line from your code as well

Comment: infobar is hided. But issue cannot hide "Disable developer mode extensions pop up in Chrome" pop.
I used next option:
                var options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.AddArgument("--test-type");
                options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
                options.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation"); 
                options.AddArguments("start-maximized");

Comment: As workaround add options.AddAdditionalOption("useAutomationExtension",false)

Comment: useAutomationExtension = false do not work @RahulL . "Developer mode extension..." still exit, though I need to use my extension for automate process. I used these option: chromeOptions.AddArguments("disable-infobars");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-blink-features=BlockCredentialedSubresources");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-notifications");
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("enable_do_not_track", true);
chromeOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);
chromeOptions.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation");

Comment: @duong-khang chromeOptions.useAutomationExtension. is only for  clients to enable or disable the 'ChromeDriver automation extension' If you are loading some other extension i think you will get the ""Developer mode extension.." message

Comment: so is there any way to get rid of this pop up? it user do not click outside the pop up then the automation process will be stuck there

Comment: As of now not aware of any other way. If you are ok with " "Chrome is being controlled by automated software..." message then remove chromeOptions.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation"); . You will not get ""Developer mode extension.." message

Answer (score 17):

*Chromium* team earlier introduced the infobar *`Chrome is being controlled by automated test software`* to disable `Developer mode extension` popup within Chrome Browser through this [commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/7a66b24c10161a5db8668729a97ac95cee9068e2).

As per the discussion [Flakiness due to Chrome automation infobar (Chrome 57+)](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1683) with the addition of the **infobar** to display *if a session is being controlled by an automated test* within Chrome it was observed that the presence of Chrome automation infobar *`Chrome is being controlled by automated test software`* intermitently caused the `click()` function to fail. During the tests, when the the infobar was removed by passing `disable-infobars` within `chrome_launcher.cc`  then the above tests runs as expected without any issues. [gmanikpure@chromium.org](https://bugs.chromium.org/u/4261869014/) confirmed that the culprit was the [changelog](http://crrev.com/450257):

```
Add an infobar if a session is being controlled by an automated test.

This infobar is only displayed if the browser is launched with the --enable-automation switch. It also disables the developer mode extensions warning bubble.

TEST=launch with and without --enable-automation, and check for presence of automation infobar
```

It was observed that, during a click the infobar animation occurs and we got flaky results. So *Chromium* team needed to detect this change somehow and recompute the position. The actual problem was, if a *Page.frameResized* occured we can invalidate the results of some operations and retry (e.g. get element position) but there were other operations that can modify the page, such as mouse clicks. It's possible that a mouse click (which involves a mousemove, mousedown and a mouseup event) can have a resize event in the middle.

Accordingly, *Chromium* team released a revision through this [commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/624a92b3c8fde51c3db67061dc460674a94ebf3b):

```
Disable info bar animations during automated testing.
```

Since then *Chrome* user, to disable the infobar started using:

- Java:

  ```
  options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
  ```
- Python:

  ```
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  ```
- C#:

  ```
  option.AddArguments("disable-infobars");
  ```

---

Now in the discussion [Chrome is being controlled by automated test software infobar doesn't gets suppressed despite using disable-infobars argument](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3050#c3) *Chromium* team member [triciac@chromium.org](https://bugs.chromium.org/u/1356571735/) clearly mentioned:

> As of v 76,  the ability to suppress the infobar was moved from command line options to Enterprise Policy settings for Chrome.

The change was already mentioned in the [*Release Notes*](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/75.0.3770.142..76.0.3809.87?pretty=fuller&n=10000) and [Chrome Enterprise release notes](https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/OLsgXtHL1zI9wMRrYXz45RlyeE493yOrmTpj) as follows

```
--disable-infobars is no longer supported

Chrome will no longer support the --disable-infobars flag, which was used to hide pop-up warnings
from Chrome Browser. To support automated testing, kiosks, and automation, the
CommandLineFlagSecurityWarningsEnabled policy was added to allow you to disable some security
warnings.
```

So, from *Chrome v76.x* onwards `--disable-infobars` flag is officially deprecated.

---

### Conclusion

The policy is not an *option* or a *capability* that is set when ChromeDriver or Chrome is launched as security policies are typically managed by your corporate IT department. Hence usage of **`disable-infobars`** have been deprecated.

---

### A small Hack

The `--disable-infobars` flag can still removed from *Chrome v76.x* using these 2(two) *ExperimentalOption*:

- **`Excluding`** the switches for `enable-automation`
- Setting `useAutomationExtension` to **`False`**

### Implementations

Here are the implementations:

- Java:

  ```
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("start-maximized");
  options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
  options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  driver.get("https://google.com");
  ```
- Python:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
  ```

---

### Outro

As per the article [CommandLineFlagSecurityWarningsEnabled](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=CommandLineFlagSecurityWarningsEnabled):

```
Enable security warnings for command-line flags

Supported on: Google Chrome (Linux, Mac, Windows) since version 76

Description: If disabled, prevents security warnings from appearing when Chrome is launched with some potentially dangerous command-line flags.
             If enabled or unset, security warnings are displayed when some command-line flags are used to launch Chrome.
             On Windows, this policy is only available on instances that are joined to a Microsoft Active Directory domain or Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise instances that are enrolled for device management.
```

Comment: Since Chrome version 79 it is no longer supported

Comment: Why would someone want to disable chrome infobar ?

Comment: @MasterJoe2 in some cases (mine included) the infobar causes the click() function to fail. Some tests can if fail the element is in the DOM but not visible in the viewport. The infobar seems to push the website's viewport down a little bit, hence making otherwise elements unclickable

Answer (score 3):

This will work in C#:

```cs
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--incognito");
chromeOptions.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation");
chromeOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);
```

Answer (score 2):

To hide "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software" infobar in C# for Chrome v76:

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
...
chromeOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);
chromeOptions.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation");
...
var driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(), chromeOptions, commandTimeout);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use `--app=desired_address_without_brackets` flag, e.g. `--app=https://google.com`. Works in Chrome 80.
   Of course it works only if it's acceptable for your project to be launched in App mode and you have a page link you can insert there. See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60287179/12690913) for a little more info.
2. You can also use `--test-type` command line flag, which removes such infobars too. 
   Attention! *In very rare cases it causes strange things like muting page sound!* So I'm not sure I should recommend it in the first place.

Comment: what is the app mode ?

Comment: Not sure, nevertheless you can see this:
https://www.auslogics.com/en/articles/google-chrome-in-application-mode/

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, for the selenium-webdriver gem, which is often used with Capybara, use `::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options#add_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation'])`.

For example:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  browser_options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
  browser_options.add_option 'excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation']
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: browser_options)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option in Ruby for me was:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: chrome_options)
end

def chrome_options
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
  options.add_option 'excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation']
  options.add_argument('incognito')
  options.add_argument('disable-geolocation')
  options.add_argument('ignore-certificate-errors')
  options.add_argument('disable-popup-blocking')
  options.add_argument('disable-web-security')
  options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
  options.add_argument('disable-translate')
  options
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can use the **CommandLineFlagSecurityWarningsEnabled** chrome policy - https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#CommandLineFlagSecurityWarningsEnabled

On Linux I was able to create a file at /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/managed_policies.json with the contents: `{"CommandLineFlagSecurityWarningsEnabled": false}` and this disabled the warning.

On Windows 10 Pro when I set the Chrome group policy "Enable security warnings for command-line flags" to disabled (see https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187202) and check the registry at Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\CommandLineFlagSecurityWarningsEnabled for a value of 0x00000000 it doesn't work for me to disable this warning. Maybe it will for you? Wondering if someone else can help shed light on why it won't work on Windows

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned above, in Java just use:

`chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches",Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));`

since:

```
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
```

is deprecated, and works same way.