# What is useAutomationExtension capability of Chrome?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I came across a problem while running Selenium tests. One of the SO answers suggested to disable Chrome Automation Extension using `useAutomationExtension` -

```
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
```

I want to understand what exactly `useAutomationExtension` is.  So I'll be able to figure out what impact it will have on tests and decide if to disable or not.

Comment: Probably [this](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Q0kuHgU1d-sj8gePjEU9nHtlQzz5rNvvGH8fCJ3iBq4/edit).

Comment: Does [this story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57298901/unable-to-hide-chrome-is-being-controlled-by-automated-software-infobar-within/57317146#57317146) addresses your concern?

Answer (score 3):

The `useAutomationExtension: false` option disables the driver to install other chrome extensions, such as `CaptureScreenshot` and others.

Comment: Could you provide source?

Comment: check out this [link](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/test/chromedriver/chrome/automation_extension.h?g=0)

Comment: but seems this capability is deprecated?